# Multiple formsauthentifications in the same application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

I was wondering if it is possible to use two different formsauthentification logins with the following directory structure:

/default.aspx
/login.aspx
/web.config
/subdirectory/sublogin.aspx
/subdirectory/subdefault.aspx
/subdirectory/web.config

The web.config in the root contains the following settings:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms  protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" loginUrl="~/login.aspx" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

What I want to achieve is, that all directories except 'subdirectory' are protected by the login.aspx in the root. 'subdirectory' has its own login.aspx (sublogin.aspx)

How would the correct content of the web.config in subdirectory look like?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want two logins? Can you use one login form and just control access to your subdirectory with the "location" tag, or some other form? Is it that you want users to login twice for that subdirectory?

Comment: I have no explicit use case for this. I got asked about this, answered that it was possible because I thought I've done something similiar. Due to I was unable to find that piece of sourecode I started writing a testapplication and failed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<authentication>` web.config section can only be defined in machine.config or in the application's root web.config. It cannot be specified in sub-folders of your application.

What you can do, however, is create another ASP.NET application that happens to exist within the other application. Then each one can have its own authentication settings. In this case they will be separate applications, though, which might cause other problems.

Comment: I am not sure this is strictly true. Can you please quote your reference, as I could not verify this on MSDN.

Comment: On http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e.aspx scroll down to the bottom where it says "Configurable locations" and it lists the following: Machine.config, Root-level Web.config, Application-level Web.config.